Wiring shed using 50A RV cord with plug?
I would like to make use of the extra 50amp plug at my campsite by supplying my shed with power.  I am not allowed to bury any wires, so I was thinking I could wire a sub panel in the shed which is fed by a 50amp rv cord plugged into extra 50amp outlet on my pedestal.  Shed is located next to my deck and I thought I could stretch Rv cord under deck when I am using shed.
Is this a stupid idea?
What size/type panel would I need? From reading other posts most people suggest picking panel based on having more spaces than I need.
I was thinking of putting lights on 1 circuit, plugs on second circuit, and a portable air conditioner on a third circuit.
Any suggestions or advice?

You need a sub panel of at least 50 amps or larger.  For future having more spaces is better, than having a panel too small and need replacing.  Check with local regulations(building/electrical) to make sure it is allowed.

Can you please state where you are, and if you're renting this campsite? Location and legal oversight may have a bearing on what answers you can get.

Digression: It took me a moment to get past "what is a wiring shed?" and parse the question correctly..

Do you need more than 20 Amps in your shed?
